# Prove using a combinatorial argument the following statement: $\binom{n+m}{2} = \binom{m}{2} + \binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{1}\binom{m}{1}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

$$\binom{n+m}{2} = \binom{m}{2} + \binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{1}\binom{m}{1}$$

I already proved this algebraically by using the formula for choose, but I don't know what exactly the question means by "combinatorial" and don't know how to start.

Thanks.

Comment: You can find some answers using combinatorial arguments also in [this recent question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958417/simplify-binommn2-binomm2-binomn2) on the same topic.

Answer (score 3):

Consider an $m$-element set $M$ and an $n$-element set $N$ such that $M\cap N=\varnothing$, so $M\cup N$ is an $(m+n)$-element set.  The left side of your equation is the number of $2$-element subsets of $M\cup N$.  These $2$-element subsets are of $3$ sorts: subsets of $M$, subsets of $N$, and subsets consisting of one element from $M$ and one from $N$.  There are $m$ choose $2$ sets of the first sort, $n$ choose $2$ of the second, and $m\cdot n$ of the third.

Comment: makes sense, thanks. But what about this proof makes it combinatorial?

Comment: To me, "combinatorial" means that the quantities in the question are interpreted as the cardinalities of some sets, rather than as algebraic formulas.

Comment: Take a example and then see whether it gives the same as i hardly think there exists a formula

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this counts as a combinatorial argument, but if you know that this is [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number):
$$T_{n-1}=\binom n2= 1+2+\dots+(n-1)$$
You can see this from picture that $$T_{m-1}+T_{n-1}+mn=T_{m+n-1}.$$

[image]

Or simply by rewriting the sums:
\begin{align*}
\binom {m+n}2 &= 1+2+\dots+(m-1)+m+(m+1)+\dots+(m+n-1)\\
&= 1+2+\dots+(m-1)+(m\cdot n)+1+\dots+n-1\\
&=\binom m2+mn+\binom n2
\end{align*}